# Change dragging state for all markers

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using Leaflet.markercluster 1.0.1

I'm trying to add button on my map, so users can enter in 'edit mode'. On click on that button it should toggle dragging state for all markers. I don't really know how to implement that correctly, but I wrote that code

```
var drag = false;
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    drag = !drag;
    markers.eachLayer(function (marker) {
        marker.options.draggable = drag;
        if (marker.dragging) {
            drag ? marker.dragging.enable() : marker.dragging.disable();
        }
    });
});
```

It works for some time, but then I get Exception on .enable()

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

Is anyone know any correct way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please run your code using `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js` and get a full stack trace from the error?

Comment: @IvanSanchez http://jsfiddle.net/Pe5xU/644/ Steps to reproduce: click 'hi', click on cluster (2), move one of markers a little bit, ensure that they will collapse into cluster (2) again, 'hi' and next click on 'hi' leading to exception

Comment: I forgot to include leaflet-src :) updated http://jsfiddle.net/Pe5xU/645/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the logic for the `forEach` method in `MarkerClusterGroup` iterates through markers not visible on the map after dragging a spiderified marker. Then the logic for enabling dragging fails, as the marker does not have an icon instance, because it has been removed from the map.

I've cleaned up the reproducible example a bit, and left a copy at https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/qate/1/edit?html,output - I strongly suggest that you turn this into a [good bug report](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) in the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

You may also check if each of the markers has a `marker._map` private property to check if they are on the map, and skip those which are not, but this may lead to other issues down the road.